# Hook or Task to modify files after pull request in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, githooks, pull-request

I would like to modify some files in my protected master-branch after a pull-request from a feature-branch to the master-branch is done in Azure DevOps Server.

One file needs to be renamed, another file needs to be created and a in a third file there is a string to replace.

Is this possible through server side git hooks or an Azure Pipeline or Task (sorry, I´m new to this topic).

**Update**

The hook or pipeline should do following:

1. check if a file current.sql has any content (if yes, go to next step)
2. update an integer-variable (DbVersion) in a C#-Class (add 1 to it)
3. rename the current.sql file to db_update_[new DbVersion].sql
4. create a new empty current.sql file

Comment: Why would this not be part of the pull request in the first place?

Comment: It could also be part of the pull request, but the file changes should be done by the pipeline or a hook. The changes should also be comitted to the master branch if the pull request gets completed.

Comment: @Martin Why the file changes should be done by the pipeline or a hook? Since it's a protected master-branch, why do you want to modify it through a pipeline or a hook? Could you elaborate your scenario with more details?

Comment: We want to use feature-branches in our new workflow. Every feature may have some db changes, which are currently located in files like db_update_123.sql. In addition to this file we have a property DbVersion in the code which reflects to the latest db_update-file.
With feature-branches we don´t know which will be the correct db_version during development, because another feature may be merged back to master-branch before the feature I'm working on. So we want the pull-request to handle the versioning automatically for us. We write all changes during a feature-branch in a current.sql-file.

Comment: Check my update in the question

Comment: @Martin How did you protect the master-branch? Since the master-branch is protected, it's supposed not able to modify this branch unless meet the branch policy.

Comment: Currently we dont protect the master branch, we even don´t use feature-branches. We just plan to switch to feature-branches and would like to update the master-branch only through pull-requests. In my imagination I would like to do the db-updates automaticaly inside the pull request. If there is no way to do this automaticaly every developer has to do this before he/she starts a new pull request.

Comment: @Martin Pull requests let your team review code and give feedback on changes before merging it into the master branch. The changes should be done before pull request.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT If you can not answer the question, no need to comment. azure devops helps to automate processes. it can be neccessary to update something automatically during/after a pull request with the goal that a human DOES NOT do this change. Because it is error prone or just to not waste human resources on chores.

Comment: @Martin did you find a solution for your problem? i have the same issue right now.

Comment: We got completely rid of the DbVersion-Variable so we don´t need to update our branch on a pull-request

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario description is a bit vague, but I will try to write some answer based on what I understand you want to do:

Generally, it is not good practice to modify your branch in your build pipeline. As mentioned before, you should do that before merging the pull request in to your branch.

For what you describe it might be good to know, that Git handles versioning automatically. Each commit creates a new version of the changed file, which you can find in the commit history in Azure DevOps. It sounds to me as if you basically just don't want to loose the edits you made in your .sql file.

If you, though, require the new version of the file to be part of the build artifact which your pipeline creates, it might make sense to write a short shell script, which you can run via a [shell script task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/shell-script?view=azure-devops). For string replacement, use the ["Replace token" task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens).

**Another solution** might be a pre-push githook, which would execute a shell script creating the new file? You can read more about githooks [here](https://githooks.com/).

I hope you found something useful in this, otherwise it would be good to know what you want to do with the versions that you create. Are you going to use the versions lateron? Maybe it might be better to reconsider a different branching model, which supports multiple environments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need the db_update_[version].sql files to make incremental Updates on a customer system. When the new Version of my software is installed on a customer system, an install tool looks for the current db-version on the system and does all missing updates (db_update_[installed_version+1].sql ... db_update_[NewDbVersion].sql in sequence.

Comment: That sounds to me like you are talking about migrations? That is well managed in EntityFramework, which I would recommend if it works for your scenario. Also sorry for the late response 